# calculation of needed zoom in postGIS based on extent

Tags: postgis, leaflet

Is there someway in postGIS to calculate the zoom I would need in my webapplication (leaflet.js) to visualize the full extent of a geo table? I know i can get it on Leaflet.js passing its bounds, but I need to calculate in postGIS.

I can get the centroid and the extent of my geo_table like this

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_centroid(extent(the_geom))), ST_AsText(extent(the_geom)) 
FROM my_geo_table
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because it depends on map's size. In other words, it's possible if the size is fixed(with little math!). Refer [leaflet source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/Map.js#L359).